# Every time I want to update / install applications always appears an error like this. how do I fix this? trims

Tags: 14.04

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'docker.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.list.save.4' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.list.save.5' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.list.save.4' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'docker.list.save.5' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Comment: Do you use docker?

Comment: that file `docker.list.save.*` is created when you use a certain editor and it creates backups as __docker.list.save.*__,  just delete those files (in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory) and the error will go away. What text editor are you using ?

Comment: Yeep, im using Docker engine

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This problem has been resolved. yes, that's right, this may result from text editor. i am using Atom.